# Is there a regex to find a string between two forward slashes and after a specific string? [R]

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a dataframe with a column that contains URls like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/nameofpage/posts/13142894231
```

I am trying to extract only the `nameofpage` portion of this column into a new column. I cannot figure out how to extract the string at that exact position. The string sometimes contains a literal ".", text, and numbers.

I have been trying to use `strsplit` and `separate` from tidyr with limited success.

The tidyr code looks like this:

```
  separate(Link, c(NA, NA, NA, "target"), sep = "/")
```

However, this really does not work at all.

I would expect to extract the `nameofpage` into the column, but sometimes the output is actually another piece of the URL.

Comment: which is that specific string after which you want to check? Also can you add more examples?

Comment: *"between two forward slashes and after a specific string"* So what is the "specific" string?

Comment: The problem is that the string is always different. Sometimes it is simply text, sometimes text with numbers, sometimes text with a literal "." somewhere, or a combination of all three. I am just trying to get the ```nameofpage``` string, so it always comes after "facebook.com/".

Comment: Another option similar to G5W's solution but for more then one element: `sapply(strsplit(c(x, x), split = "/", fixed = TRUE), "[[", 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition there's also [`str_match`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_match), which will return matched groups within a regular expression:

```
str_match(url, "://(.*?)/(.*?)(\/|$)")[,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split` from the `stringr` package.

```
URL = "https://www.facebook.com/nameofpage/posts/13142894231"

library(stringr)

str_split(URL, "/")
[[1]]
[1] "https:"           ""                 "www.facebook.com" "nameofpage"      
[5] "posts"            "13142894231"     

str_split(URL, "/")[[1]][4]
[1] "nameofpage"
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `str_split` instead of base `str.split`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function to work on your strings:

```
get.nameofpage = function(string){
  (unlist(strsplit(string, "\\/")))[4]
}

# Example
my.string = "https://www.facebook.com/nameofpage/posts/13142894231"
> get.nameofpage(my.string)
[1] "nameofpage"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub`. This returns at least one `+` character after .com that is not a forward-slash `[^/]`:

```
link <- "https://www.facebook.com/nameofpage/posts/13142894231"

gsub("^.*\\.com/([^/]+).*", "\\1", link)
[1] "nameofpage"
```

Note: this will only work for a url with ".com" (i.e., it would not work for other domains .edu, .org, etc.)

Comment: Only going to work for `.com` pages, not for any oterh domain type.

Comment: @42- Very true--OP said in a comment above it would always come after "facebook.com". I'll add an edit for clarity though

Answer (score 0):

There is some question regarding exactly what we know about the position of the desired field but if we know it is the 4th /-separated field or 3rd from last we can use (1) or (2) respectively.  (IF neither of these can be assumed please clarify exactly how we know which field is desired.)

**1) read.table** Using the character vector `ss` in the Note below as input we can use `read.table` if we know that the desired field is between the third and fourth slash.

```
read.table(text = ss, sep = "/", fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)[[4]]
## [1] "nameofpage" "nameofpage"
```

**1a)**  Using `separate`:

```
library(tidyr)

separate(data.frame(ss), ss, c(NA, NA, NA, "target"), sep = "/", extra = "drop")
##       target
## 1 nameofpage
## 2 nameofpage
```

**2) dirname/basement**  We can use `dirname` and `basename` if we know that the desired field is the third past field:

```
basename(dirname(dirname(ss)))
## [1] "nameofpage" "nameofpage"
```

### Note

```
s <- "https://www.facebook.com/nameofpage/posts/13142894231"
ss <- c(s, s)
```